# Many to Many Mapping / Seed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mapping

I have 3 models with mapping.

The problem is when i try seed them i get NullReferenceException.

```
    [Table("Articles")]
public class Article
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

[Table("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

[Table("Comments")]
public class Comment
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}

    public ArticleMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        this.HasMany(m => m.Comments);

        this.HasMany(m => m.Tags);
    }

    public CommentMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        this.HasRequired(m => m.Article);
    }

    public TagMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        this.HasMany(m => m.Articles);
    }
```

**And this is the way i seed data:**

```
protected override void Seed(MychineContext context)
    {
        Article article = new Article();
        article.Title = "Looking for trouble";
        article.Date = DateTime.Now;
        article.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

        context.Articles.Add(article);

        Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.Name = "PHP";
        tag.Articles.Add(article);

        article.Tags.Add(tag);

        context.Articles.Attach(article);

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

Is this mapping correct? If i use "migration" i will need reset all data every time?

Comment: The NullReference could happen anywhere in the project. It doesn't necessarily mean that your mapping is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answer.

I solved the problem.

The tags is a list and i forgot to create instance before add tags.